# Ajax reques x number of times is it possible to have end result from one of the previous requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, request

Is it possible this scenario.

A user clicks on a button which makes an ajax call to MVC c# controller action which does heavy calculations and returns a json.
If the user clicks the button quickly x number of times is it possible in the end the last json result to be a result from one of the previous x-1 requests?

Comment: Is the order guaranteed by the way TCP/IP works?

Comment: What's the desired behavior?  (Would you consider adding a timer at the server? or better yet a control in javascript?)

Comment: The last click on the button to be processed last. But if the processing speed of the requests is different then I am not sure if that is what is going to happen

Comment: What's the use case where someone can click the button quickly?  If the user is playing a game I might understand that. A business site, heck no!  Pretend you are (simulating) streaming audio in small files from a server.  No guarantee that the files will arrive in the order sent.  Use a counter, if the audio file is out of order, delete it.  Obviously a lot depends on your specific use case..

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, YES, it is possible.  It's not even that unlikely.

Comment: Do you know any way to queue the requests for example and make sure that the last result have came from the last request. I guess one obvious solution is to prevent multiple requests. Another will be the ajax request to abort the previous request and then execute itself. I am not sure how this will affect the server part - I guess in case of MVC Controller will still execute the request, but just the javascript part will not expect results.

Comment: The simple way is to build your own queue of requests, and when one request comes in, then request the next in the queue.  Or as you said, cancel the previous request and issue a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible depending on the processing speed of requests.

I faced a similar problem with suggestion drop downs. User types input quickly and results gets appended in incoherent manner.

Comment: How did you solved that issue in your case? Did you abort the last request before making a new one?

Comment: It's a bit different. Whenever a new request got triggered I will remove old results and start taking new results into consideration and use them